# My location button event listener

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I enabled the my-location layer of the Google Maps Android API v2, which adds the floating button to go to the user's current location. I need a way to detect a click on this button. Is this possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, currently there is no way to get that information. There is a feature request raised for that and it is already Acknowledged by Google.

Star it if you want a quicker fix:

http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4789&q=apitype%3DAndroid2&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal

---

Workaround:

Disable the built-in control and create your own View and add it to the screen. Set an onClickListener to this button and animate the map to the map's location.

Disable the default control:

```
UiSettings.setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false)
```

Get my location from the map:

```
GoogleMap.getMyLocation()
```

Comment: This is no longer true, Android has updated. See Tony's or my answer below.

Answer (score 53):

Since this question was posted, Google has updated the API. They have added an `onMyLocationButtonClick()` listener.

To add the listener:

```
//add location button click listener
map.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick()
    {
        //TODO: Any custom actions
        return false;
    }
});
```

Returning false will essentially call the super method. Returning true will not.

Answer (score 29):

The latest release of Google Maps android api V2 in August contains a listener method for clicks of my location button : **[onMyLocationButtonClick ()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener)** This can be used to know when the user has clicked the button and returns true if the listener has consumed the event

Answer (score 0):

This is good to know as I was also wondering about this. Now, is there a way to know whether or not Google's location service is enabled so we can decide whether or not we want to enable the button or not? No sense having a button that doesn't do anything so the workaround (disabling that button always) seems to be the only option for now.