# Listener for new Button to get my location in GMaps v2

Tags: android, button, listener, google-maps-android-api-2

I think that it is a really noob question but i could not do it.

In new Google maps API for Android (v2) you can get you location right now touching the new button that appears on the map when you code:

```
myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

That's works fine but I want to "catch" the event when the user touch this button because i want to add more actions and I don't know how to reference that button in code.

Anyone knows?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you mean, that your map should center the map on your current location via my-location-button, this works for me! Make sure, that you initialized your location listeners correctly. Check this out!
https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/MapsV2/Location/src/com/commonsware/android/mapsv2/location/MainActivity.java

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14777951/my-location-button-event-listener?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: The button (when you press it) goes to your current location automatically with animation camera included to center your location (it is the button in the corner up to the right. I just want to do more stuffs when user touch it but it seems that listener for that button is not implemented (yet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener) was just announced. probably going to be released today in the next Google APIs version.

Comment: yeah! i've seen that this morning... glad to hear it!! More information: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/releases#august_2013

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible via the api.

A feature request is already pending and I think this will be added soon.

See this: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4789

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will be alert about it. It can be really usefull.

Answer (score 0):

Oh yes, sorry. I should have read your question more clearly.

In order to your question:

In those situations, I recommened that you layout out your own my-location-button on the mapView and add a clicklistener on that and over location-listener, you can get the current position.

```
map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude, longitude), zoom));
```

Comment: yes, you are right. I thought about that way but I wanted to use the new button. It looks fine and the code is very simple, so easy. If they don't leave an listener to this button soon, i will do it manually. Thanks

Comment: If you want to add a comment after this, click add comment button below to add it.

Comment: By the way, on Samsung Galaxy S2 2.3.3 the built-in map controller buttons have a white vertical bar on right side ;). Looks terrible!