# Marker current location android google map?

Tags: android, android-maps-v2, android-maps, android-maps-utils

How I can use from bellow marker for my map ?

I don't need to use `mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);`.I just need to this icon.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
GoogleMapOptions options = new GoogleMapOptions();
options.mapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE)
    .compassEnabled(true)
    .rotateGesturesEnabled(false)
    .tiltGesturesEnabled(false);
```

for details check this link.

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/UiSettings
or
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/controls

I use from this link and good work :

[alazsbalazs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14778118/4813855)