# How can I update my location with Google Maps?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-location

I know that if I use this, I can get my location, but how can I get it automatically or by clicking a button; How can I update my location?

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(this.getLocation(), 16));
    MarkerOptions a = new MarkerOptions().position(this.getLocation());
    m = mMap.addMarker(a);
}

private LatLng getLocation() {
    LatLng location = null;
    gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);
        if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
            double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
            double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
            location = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        return location;

    } else {
        gps.showSettingsAlert();
        location = new LatLng(-23.036602, -13.183594);
        return location;
    }
}
```

The only way I could do this was by restarting the activity, but I think this is not the best solution.

Comment: Maybe https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html

Comment: You have to use a LocationListener which will call LocationChanged. See the [Google documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html#updates).

Comment: Thanks Fllo, I'll attend to the next one.

Comment: cricket_007 But I did not want it to be constant, just in the click, my users did not always need the GPS connected.

Comment: But it's already a way, thank you

Comment: Little search on SO and found these topics: [How to get the current location in Google Maps Android API v2?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23943952/2668136) - [My location button event listener](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18575472/2668136)