# Can't change zoom in onMyLocationButtonClick event

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, android-location, android-maps-v2

I want that if the user presses the MyLocation button of the top-right corner of the map, the zoom must be setted this way:

```
implements OnMyLocationButtonClickListener
.
.
.
mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
.
.
.
@Override
public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {
    if (mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom<16){
        Log.d("XXXX","Zoom is "+mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom+" so animating it to 16");
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(16));
    }
    return false;
}
```

The log is correctly printing lines like these:

```
Zoom is 13.0 so animating it to 16
Zoom is 11.0 so animating it to 16
.
.
.
```

But the zoom is not changing, the button is simply centering the screen to the user blue dot location without applying the zoom.

Is something wrong in the code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30878138/3268303

Comment: hi @dazza5000 what do you want from me to understand with that link in relation with my question?

Comment: Try returning 'true' instead - false indicates the default behavior is to occur on return - I can't say whether that includes a default zoom (which would override your attempt).  Try it and see...

Comment: @Andy I havn't tested but I am pretty sure what you said will resolve the issue. I would suggest posting it as the answer